# jQuery - dynamic variables?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, variables

Newbie question.  Given the following html.

```
<div id="mycontainer1" class="container">
<input type="text" class="name"/>
<input type="text" class="age"/>
</div>

<div id="mycontainer2" class="container">
<input type="text" class="name"/>
<input type="text" class="age"/>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create a function where I can pass an element id and an array that contains the classes of the input values I want to get.

So for example,

```
var inputClasses = ['name','age'];

getInputValue('.container', inputClasses);


     function getInputValue(elem, arr) {    
            $(elem).each(function() {
                // need a way to map items in array to variables

                // but how do I do this dynamically?
                var nameValue = $(this).find('.name').val();
                var ageValue = $(this).find('.age').val();

            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var inputClasses = ['name','age'];

console.log(getInputValues('#mycontainer1', inputClasses));

function getInputValues(elem, arr) {
  return $(elem).find("." + arr.join(",.")).map(function(val) {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();
}
```

Comment: I think you want `find( '.' + arr.join(',.'))`.

Comment: Might want to tag a `get()` on the end as well if a basic array instead of jQuery is desired as the output.

Comment: This is a great.  If I understand correctly this gets single input value at a time.  Is there a way to get multiple input values on each iteration?

Comment: BTW in my original post I meant to find elements by class NOT by id.

should be getInputValue('.container', inputClasses);

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var inputClasses = ['name','age'];
var inputValues = getInputValue('#myContainer1', inputClasses);

 function getInputValue(elem, arr) {
     var out = [];

            for(i=0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
                var out[arr[i]] = $(elem+' .'+arr[i]).val();
            };

     return out;
}
```

You should now have an array `inputValues` that contains the values of every input field, with the class name as the index key.

For example, you could then read out the "name" value like this:

```
alert('Your name: '+inputValues['name']);
```